# HashMap adding object with equals true and same hashcode

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I am trying to create custom objects for `HashMap` and have written code for `hashcode` and `equals` method. While adding objects in `HashMap`, `equals` method is true and `hashcode` is returning same value for both objects yet `HashMap` is adding both objects as different objects. How can this be possible?
Below is my code:

```
class B {
    String name;
    int id;

    public B(String name, int id)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
    }

    public boolean equals(B b){
        if(this==b)
            return true;
        if(b==null)
            return false;
        if(this.name.equals(b.name) && this.id==b.id)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int hashcode(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "name: "+name+" id: "+id;
    }
}
```

For testing above code, I have added following in my main class:

```
HashMap<B,String> sample=new HashMap<>();
B b1 = new B("Volga",1);
B b2 = new B("Volga",1);
System.out.println(b1.equals(b2));
System.out.println(b1.hashcode()+"    "+b2.hashcode());
sample.put(b1, "wrog");
sample.put(b2,"wrog");
System.out.println(sample);
```

This is producing following output:

```
true
1    1
{name: Volga id: 1=wrog, name: Volga id: 1=wrog}
```

Can someone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Your equals method does not override the one from Object. It should take Object as argument, not B.

Comment: **always** add the `@Override`annotation to a method which is supposed to override or implement a method. Not only that doecuments it, but if you make the mistake you just made, the compiler will refuse to compile.

Comment: Also there's typo in `hashcode`. It should be `hashCode` with capital `C`...

Comment: Thanks, I missed that and it was the issue. its working fine now!!!

Answer (score 7):

You've got two issues here:

1. Instead of implementing `equals(B)` you should have implemented `equals(Object)` ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-))
2. It needs to be `hashCode()` instead of `hashcode()` ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--))

A working implementation *might* look like this:

```
class B {
    String name;
    int id;

    public B(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        B other = (B) obj;
        if (id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + " id: " + id;
    }
}
```

As a general advise, make sure to specify the `@Override` annotation. Your IDE and the Java compiler (`javac`) can then help you spot these kind of issues.

Comment: "if you're working in an IDE, like Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, Netbeans and the like, make sure to specify the @Override annotation." The check is not related to IDE features. `@Override` will produce a compilation error. So just javac is enough to detect that.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are neither overriding the `hashCode`, nor the `equals` method of `java.lang.Object`, due to a typo (`hashcode` is what you used) and usage of a wrong parameter in the `equals` method.

An actual implementation which works for both would be:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    B b = (B) o;
    return id == b.id &&
            Objects.equals(name, b.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, id);
}
```

This implementation was actually generated by IntelliJ IDEA. What I actually like about this implementation is that it uses the `java.util.Objects.hash()` method which simplifies the generation of `hashCode` a lot and was introduced in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the `equals(Object)` & `hashCode()` methods instead of `equals(B b)` & `hashcode()`.

Try to implement the methods with following signature & it should work:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){...}

@Override
public int hashCode() {...}
```

You could also use your IDE's autogenerate feature to generate these methods. That way, there are no chances of error.